# Buffered and Cache memory in Solaris

Tags: unix, solaris

how to get the Buffer, Cache memory and Block in-out in Solaris ?  For Example: In Linux I can get it using vmstat.  vmstat in Linux gives

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
```

Where as vmstat in Solaris doesn't give buff and cache under `------memory----`. Also there is no `-----io----`. How to get these fields on Solaris ?

Comment: iostat, zonestat (for zones), and in a global zone or non-zoned machine: echo ::memstat|mdb -k. If you have sar enabled there are lots more detailed reports.

Comment: Thanks jim. iostat -x gives lots of columns. Out of those which fields are equivalent to bi and bo under ------io----- ? memstat takes much time. Is there an alternative for memstat ?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel memory:

```
kstat -p > /var/tmp/kstat-p
```

more details kernel memory statistics:

```
 kstat -p -c kmem_cache
 kstat -p -m vmem
 kstat -p -c vmem
```

alternative:

```
 echo “::kmastat” | mdb -k > /var/tmp/kmastat
```

Do not use iostat that way,

try to show busy disks with realtime sampling (you want this to start with):

```
iostat -xmz 2 4  # -> 2 seconds sampling time,  4 sampling intervals
```

show historical average data:

```
iostat -xm
```

Comment: Thanks once again Jim. :-)